# VB Excel 2010 code to select and copy between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still learning VB. I tried recording a VB script in excel 2010 that selects a name on the main sheet, then goes to another sheet and finds all the rows with that name, copies all the rows and returns to the main sheet and insert the copied cells below the selected name. The cells are pushed down. The code should repeat for the next name below where the copied cells were paste.

My recording failed to do all of the above. Do you have a suggestion?

```
    Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Leeanne Hickmott", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Range("A1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 6).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The way to do this is to use AutoFilter or Advanced Filter: http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter03.html#Copy, http://www.rondebruin.nl/copy5_1.htm

Comment: Which parts of your requirements did your code fail to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Excel's record macro process can't record the conditionals or loops you need to make that kind of macro work. It also can't record that you pasted a value into the find dialog, it just records that you want to search for "Leeanne Hickmott"

My first suggestion would be to use range variables to point to the important cells on each worksheet. For example...

```
Dim rngPasteHere as Range, rngCopyFrom as Range
set rngPasteHere = Selection
set rngCopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")
' find first row
set rngCopyFrom = rngCopyFrom.Cells.Find(What:=rngPasteHere.Value _
                             , After:=rngCopyFrom, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                             , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                             , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
                             , SearchFormat:=False)
```

You will also need two loops, an outer loop that repeats the whole process for the next name and an inner loop that finds all the rows with the current name. I can't really get more specific than that without knowing what your data looks like.

1. Are the names sorted alphabetically?
2. Are all rows with the same name right next to each other or are they mixed with other names?
3. Are there just a few rows of each name or thousands?

Comment: 1. Names are sorted in alphabetical order. 2. Yes. similar rows are right below each other. 3. Just a few... three to four